# What are some praise of Buddhism in philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, complexity, pain-and-pleasure

refer back to my older question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16408/what-are-some-criticism-of-buddhism-in-logic

What are some praise of Buddhism in philosophy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arthur Schopenhauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Schopenhauer) is probably the most notable example of a Western philosopher who praised ideas from the Buddhist tradition. He explicitly compared his own theory of the human will to the "Four Noble Truths" of Buddhism.

While American [Transcendentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendentalism) was more of a cultural than a philosophical movement, that might be another case where prominent thinkers in the Western tradition engaged with and supported Buddhist ideas.

There are other important thinkers (e.g. [Baruch Spinoza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinoza), [Karl Marx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Marx)) who may not have praised Buddhism directly, but for whom connections have been frequently drawn between their ideas and Buddhist ones.

Comment: Great Answer. It covers it well enough that rather than answer my own, I'd just like to add a few: There are also a number of philosophers who seem to have great affinity for Buddhist ideas within their distinctions; e.g. Camus, Heidegger, Nietzsche at times.  Also some authors who are less academically accepted as philosophers - like Alan Watts, Johnathan Swift; Milan Kundera.  Also Carl Jung was heavily influenced by The Tibetan Book Of The Dead.